# Should the internal disk of a Mac be erased?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, ssd

I saw this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/336371/322902) which said that the internal disk of a Mac should not be erased, but it doesn't explain why. Does anyone know?

Comment: Not sure where you saw "not to erase your Mac's HD" in that post. But at its basic level a Mac is just a computer and any drive can be erased. The difficulty comes in knowing how to recover from an erased disk, not especially difficult if you have some experience but a daunting task if you have no help or experience.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can always erase a disk internal or external to set it up clean. The only reason to not erase is if you want to try and recover or back up any data.

I might try to repair a disk from recovery mode once or twice, then I erase to get a clean install.