# Disk Utility multiple runs shows same warning message and is not actually repairing the disk

Tags: disk-utility, repair

Disk Utility log:

```
Running First Aid on “Machintosh I” (disk2s1)

Verifying the startup volume will cause this computer to stop responding.

Verifying file system.
Volume is already unmounted.
Live mode required because other APFS Volumes in its Container are mounted.
Using live mode.
Performing fsck_apfs -n -l -x /dev/rdisk2s1
Checking the container superblock.
Checking the EFI jumpstart record.
Checking the space manager.
Checking the space manager free queue trees.
Checking the object map.
Checking the encryption key structures.
Checking volume /dev/rdisk2s1.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
Checking the object map.
Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
Checking the snapshot metadata.
Checking snapshot 1 of 1 (com.apple.os.update-EA882DCA7A28EBA0A6E94689836BB10D77D84D1AEE2468E17775A447AA815278)
Checking the extent ref tree.
Checking the fsroot tree.
Checking the file extent tree.
Verifying volume object map space.
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3888505
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3888510 --> 3888517
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3888521
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3888523
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3888526 --> 3888538
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3888564
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3888568 --> 3888570
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3888636
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3888638
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3888640
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3888644
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3888656
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3888662
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3888666
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3888669 --> 3888670
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3888674
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3888685
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3888701
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3888725
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3888747 --> 3888749
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3888767
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3888770 --> 3888771
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3888792 --> 3888794
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3888796 --> 3888797
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3888799 --> 3888808
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3888816 --> 3888819
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3888821
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3888823
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3888830 --> 3888833
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3888878
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3888880 --> 3888881
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3888914
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3888920
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3888930
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3888933 --> 3888934
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3888937
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3888949
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3888951
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3888953 --> 3888954
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3888967 --> 3888968
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3888972 --> 3888974
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3888976 --> 3888991
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3889093
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3889096 --> 3889097
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3889134
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3889136
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3889176 --> 3889177
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3889206 --> 3889211
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3889221 --> 3889222
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3889224 --> 3889227
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3889229 --> 3889231
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3889278
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3889283
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3889358
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3889363
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3889395
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3889475
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3889480
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3889487
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3889491
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3889493 --> 3889494
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3889528 --> 3889530
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3889532 --> 3889537
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3889694
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3889696 --> 3889697
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3889703
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3889725
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3889741 --> 3889743
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3889746
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3889748
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3889750
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3889752 --> 3889756
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3889758
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3889766
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3889778
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3889784
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3889790
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3889793
warning: orphan omap mapping found for oid 3889798
Too many warnings of this type generated; suppressing subsequent ones.
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3889865 --> 3889866
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3889868 --> 3889871
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3889976 --> 3889981
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3890016 --> 3890018
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3890020 --> 3890023
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3890205 --> 3890206
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3890232 --> 3890236
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3890256 --> 3890265
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3890291 --> 3890292
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3890305 --> 3890306
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3890316 --> 3890317
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3890319 --> 3890324
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3890326 --> 3890327
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3890329 --> 3890331
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3890690 --> 3890721
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3890723 --> 3890731
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3890742 --> 3890744
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3890770 --> 3890771
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3890774 --> 3890776
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3890779 --> 3890782
warning: orphan omap mappings found for oid range 3890784 --> 3890789
Too many warnings of this type generated; suppressing subsequent ones.
warning: volume omap (fs_oid 0x399a42): 124424 orphan mappings found
The volume /dev/rdisk2s1 was found to be corrupt and needs to be repaired.
Verifying allocated space.
Performing deferred repairs.
The volume /dev/rdisk2s1 appears to be OK.
File system check exit code is 0.
Restoring the original state found as unmounted.

Operation successful.
```

Please help me understand it and repair the hard drive

Comment: You probably need to try again from Recovery. Live mode means some of the disk cannot be altered, as the system is running from it. I would also ensure your backup is up to date, in case the drive dies completely during this operation.

Comment: Tried from recovery multiple times but same log every time

Comment: Then I'd guess one last shot is to boot it from Internet Recovery or a USB stick & see if that makes any difference. If not, then it's time for a new drive, I'm afraid.

Comment: How old is this iMac?

Comment: This is 4 years old machine.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed some corrupted internal APFS SSD system drives for a Mac mini and macBook Pro running Ventura 13.2 by making an external bootable verified full-image SSD drive backup of the systems which needed repairs.

The details are posted [here in my answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336223/how-to-fix-my-corrupted-apfs-container/454150#454150) to the *"How to fix my corrupted APFS container?"* question.